# Using Tailwind CSS classes in Nuxt.js markdown content

Tags: nuxt.js, markdown, tailwind-css, nuxt-content

I'm using Nuxt with the content plugin and Tailwind typography. I'd like to use Tailwind classes inside markdown files to allow for adding some basic layout.

```html
<!-- file: content.md -->

<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
  <div>

### Some markdown...

  </div>
  <div>

### Some other markdown...

  </div>
</div>
```

Since rendered markdown in `<nuxt-content />` isn't processed with Tailwind, the classes used within it will not be included in the generated styles (except they're used elswhere in the project).

One workaround is to use a very clever Tailwind feature which will include classes that are mentioned in comments. I created a global component that includes all classes that might be used in the markdown content.

```vue
<!-- file: grid.vue -->

<template>
  <div class="grid">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
/* Tailwind CSS

  grid-cols-1
  grid-cols-2
  [...]

  gap-2
  gap-4
  [...]

*/
</style>
```

Then I just use that component in the markdown content instead:

```html
<!-- file: content.md -->

<grid class="grid-cols-2 gap-4">
  <!-- ... -->
</grid>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to run the markdown content through Tailwind somehow to pick up the classes dynamically. I'd assume it requires a custom build step but I'm not familiar enough with either Nuxt.js or Tailwind yet to know where to start.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be easily solved. I just needed to add the content folder to the Tailwind config. It's found in the [Nuxt Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/tailwind/config), although not explicitely mentioned.

```js
// file: tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  purge: {
    content: [
      // ...
      './content/**/*.md'
    ]
  }
```

Comment: This was really cool. Can you describe more how you abstracted the grid to fit different pages?

Comment: thanks for the pointer. although you don't need to use `purge` anymore. use `content` directly. via: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#configure-content-sources